# Access previous/next item when iterating over a ListDataModel using JSF 2 facelets <ui:repeat> tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, facelets, uirepeat

I'm iterating over a list and want certain attributes of the current element to be rendered only when they're different from the previous element. Right now I have:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myListDataModel}" var="item" varStatus="itemStatus">

  <ui:fragment rendered="#{
      itemStatus.first 
      or (myBean.myListDataModelUnwrapped[itemStatus.index-1].category ne item.category)
  }">
      <h1>
          <h:outputText value="#{item.category}"/>
      </h1>
      <!-- can't open a ul here -->
  </ui:fragment>

          <li>
              <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
          </li>

  <ui:fragment rendered="#{
      itemStatus.last or 
      (myBean.myListDataModelUnwrapped[itemStatus.index+1].category ne item.category)
  }">
      <!-- can't close a ul here -->
  </ui:fragment>

</ui:repeat>
```

where

```
Object[] myListDataModelUnwrapped = 
    (Object[]) ((new ArrayList((List) myListDataModel.getWrappedData())).toArray());
```

- What's a better way to access the previous/next element when iterating over a `ListDataModel`?
- How can I embed the list elements on `<ul></ul>` tags, rendering a valid unordered list below each category header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you have 2 questions and i don't have a better solution for the 1st one. i've always used your way to do it.

for the 2nd one, as a work-around, you can open and close `<ul></ul>` using `h:outputText`, as below:

xhtml code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{testMB.ulStartTag}" escape="false"/>
...
<h:outputText value="#{testMB.ulEndTag}" escape="false"/>
```

managed bean code:

```
public String getUlStartTag() {
    return "<ul>";
}

public String getUlEndTag() {
    return "</ul>";
}
```

ps: don't try to write `"<ul>"` as the value of `h:outputText` directly into the xhtml, it will fail at runtime because of the "<" and ">" characters.

Comment: That's very clever, thanks for the tip :-) I ended up building a loop of elements inside a loop of categories, to keep things clear and simple. I'm not happing adding the overhead of building the required `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s, but it's only once per session over a pretty small list, so I hope it won't have much of an impact..